# go to main activity using onBackPressed in navigationdrawer view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a mainactivity with  a fragment. but when I backpress the app closes. I want that whenever back button is pressed the app goes to main activity page from which ever fragment it is working on.

```
public
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;
    private AdView mAdView2;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView firstrecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView secondrecyclerView;
    //youtube player fragment
    private YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX youTubePlayerFragment;
    private ArrayList<String> youtubeVideoArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> secondyoutubeVideoArrayList;
    ArrayList<itemModel> items;
    ArrayList<itemModel2> items2;

    String[] iconName = {"TV9 Gujrati","NDTV india","Republic Bharat"};
    String[] iconName2 = {"Al Jazeera","Sky News","CNA Singapore","Indus Live","RT News"};

    //youtube player to play video when new video selected
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

//NavigationView
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        generateDummyVideoList();
        initializeYoutubePlayer();
        setUpRecyclerView();
        populateRecyclerView();
        // This will display an Up icon (<-), we will replace it with hamburger later
       Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        // Find our drawer view
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9681539518823208~9907474172");
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9681539518823208/1204338718");
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitialAd.loadAd(request);
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            public void onAdLoaded(){
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView2 = findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest2);


    }

    /**
     * initialize youtube player via Fragment and get instance of YoutubePlayer
     */
    private void initializeYoutubePlayer() {

        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);


        if (youTubePlayerFragment == null)
            return;

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                                boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer = player;


                    //set the player style default
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

                    //cue the 1st video by default
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoArrayList.get(0));

                    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

                //print or show error if initialization failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Player View initialization failed");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * setup the recycler view here
     */
    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        firstrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.first_recycler_view);
        firstrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        items = new ArrayList<>();

        //Horizontal direction recycler view
        LinearLayoutManager firstlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        firstrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(firstlinearLayoutManager);
        firstrecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        for (int i = 0; i < iconName.length; i++) {
            itemModel itemModel = new itemModel(iconName[i], youtubeVideoArrayList.get(i));
            items.add(itemModel);
        }
        secondrecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.second_recycler_view);
        secondrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        items2 = new ArrayList<>();

        LinearLayoutManager secondlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        secondrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(secondlinearLayoutManager);
        secondrecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        for (int i = 0; i < iconName2.length; i++) {
            itemModel2 itemModel2 = new itemModel2(iconName2[i], secondyoutubeVideoArrayList.get(i));
            items2.add(itemModel2);
        }
    }

    /**
     * populate the recycler view and implement the click event here
     */
    private void populateRecyclerView() {
        final CustomAdapter adapterf = new CustomAdapter(this, items);
        firstrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterf);
        //set click event
        firstrecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewOnClickListener(this, new RecyclerViewOnClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                if (youTubePlayerFragment != null && youTubePlayer != null) {
                    //update selected position
                    adapterf.setSelectedPosition(position);

                    //load selected video
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoArrayList.get(position));
                }

            }
        }));

        final CustomAdapter2 adapterf2 = new CustomAdapter2(this, items2);
        secondrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterf2);

        //set click event
        secondrecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewOnClickListener2(this, new RecyclerViewOnClickListener2.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view2, int position) {

                if (youTubePlayerFragment != null && youTubePlayer != null) {
                    //update selected position
                   adapterf2.setSelectedPosition(position);

                    //load selected video
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(secondyoutubeVideoArrayList.get(position));
                }

            }
        }));
    }


    /**
     * method to generate dummy array list of videos
     */
    private void generateDummyVideoList() {
        youtubeVideoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //get the video id array from strings.xml
        String[] videoIDArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.video_id_array);

        //add all videos to array list
        Collections.addAll(youtubeVideoArrayList, videoIDArray);

        secondyoutubeVideoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //get the video id array from strings.xml
        String[] secondvideoIDArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.secondvideo_id_array);

        //add all videos to array list
        Collections.addAll(secondyoutubeVideoArrayList, secondvideoIDArray);
    }
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_1:
                fragmentClass = Fragment1.class;
                break;
          default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + menuItem.getItemId());
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        assert fragment != null;
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).addToBackStack().commit();

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(false);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Close the navigation drawer
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried onBackstack but I dont want to go to previous fragment but go to main activity. I added home menu item and assigned mainactivity to that but when it is pressed from navigation drawer the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an intent?

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!drawerIsOpen()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    } else
        closeDrawer();
        
}
```

Comment: it gives error that drawerIsOpen is not a ,ethod create a method

Comment: Without using if else I just used the intent code and its working. thanks +1